# SceneKit – Geometry penetration

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit, scene, 3d-model

I import a 3D model into the ScenekKit, then change the Euler's angle of the limb and let the limbs do the action. However, at this time, clothes and limbs will penetrate. How can I handle this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use `continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold` instance property. This value gives you a minimum distance the body must travel for SceneKit to apply a more precise (but more CPU/GPU costly) algorithm to detect contacts with other bodies.

```
var continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold: CGFloat { get set }
```

> **SceneKit's physics engine can employ two kinds of collision detection**:
>
> - With ***`discrete collision`*** detection, when SceneKit simulates physics before rendering each frame (see ***timeStep*** and ***SCNSceneRendererDelegate***), it updates the position of each physics body based on the body's velocity during that time interval, then checks to see whether the body at its new position intersects other bodies.
> - With ***`continuous collision`*** detection, SceneKit calculates the volume that will be traversed by a body during each frame, then checks to see whether that volume intersects other bodies. This property's value `defaults to 0.0`, resulting in discrete collision detection at all times. When this value is nonzero, SceneKit applies continuous collision whenever the body travels more than the specified distance within one ***timeStep***.

Discrete collision detection offers high performance, but can lead to inaccurate results for small, fast-moving bodies. Continuous collision detection has a performance cost and works only for spherical physics shapes, but provides more accurate results.